pine script strategy.exit() stop not working on a live chart
On historical bars the stop works fine but on a live chart the stop doesnt work correctly. If the stop level is met it will close on bar close. The take profit exits at the correct limit price, but its like the stop is acting like a market on bar close instead of a limit. I have a large code section to give as much detail on the relevant section of the code as possible.
// calc_on_every_tick = true

// Strategy {

// global vars {

bool in_long = strategy.position_size > 0
bool in_short = strategy.position_size < 0
bool in_trade = strategy.position_size != 0
bool no_trade = strategy.position_size == 0

bool state_up = base_signal == 1
bool state_down = base_signal == 2
bool state_neutral = base_signal == 3

bool up_or_neutral = state_up or state_neutral
bool down_or_neutral = state_down or state_neutral

float take_profit_price = syminfo.mintick * take_profit_value
float stop_loss_price = syminfo.mintick * stop_loss_value
float break_even_price = syminfo.mintick * break_even_value
float breaK_even_ticks = syminfo.mintick * break_even_level

// end global vars }

// trade vars {

var int cue_state = 0
var bool long_cued = false
var bool short_cued = false
var bool neutral_cued = false

var float tp_price = na
var float entry_price = na
var float stop_price = na
var bool broke_even = false

bool stop_continuation = false

// end trade vars }

// strategy execution {

if barstate.isconfirmed
    if no_trade 
        broke_even := false
        tp_price := na
        entry_price := na
        stop_price := na
        strategy.cancel_all()

        if enable_reversal
            if reversal_up and (base_signal == 2 or base_signal == 3) and enable_long
                cue_state := base_signal
                long_cued := true
                short_cued := false
                neutral_cued := false

            if reversal_down and (base_signal == 1 or base_signal == 3) and enable_short
                cue_state := base_signal
                long_cued := false
                short_cued := true
                neutral_cued := false

            if reversal_neutral and enable_neutral and no_trade
                cue_state := base_signal

                if state_neutral 
                    long_cued := false
                    short_cued := false
                    neutral_cued := true

                if state_up and enable_short
                    long_cued := false
                    short_cued := true
                    neutral_cued := false

                if state_down and enable_long
                    long_cued := true
                    short_cued := false
                    neutral_cued := false

            if cue_state == 3
                if long_cued and state_down
                    long_cued := false
                    cue_state := 0

                if short_cued and state_up
                    short_cued := false
                    cue_state := 0

            if cancel_on_continue
                if long_cued and continuation_down
                    stop_continuation := true
                    long_cued := false
                    neutral_cued := false
                    cue_state := 0

                if short_cued and continuation_up
                    stop_continuation := true
                    short_cued := false
                    neutral_cued := false
                    cue_state := 0

            if reset_on_repaint and repaint_siginal
                if long_cued and trend == -1 and continuation
                    long_cued := false
                    cue_state := 0

                if short_cued and trend == 1 and continuation
                    short_cued := false
                    cue_state := 0
            if long_cued
                bool cue_condition = cue_state == 2 ? up_or_neutral : state_up

                if cue_condition
                    tp_price := close + take_profit_price
                    entry_price := close
                    stop_price := close - stop_loss_price

                    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, alert_message = buy_string)
                    strategy.exit("Long Exit", "Long", stop = stop_price, limit = tp_price, alert_profit = close_trade, alert_loss = close_trade)

                    cue_state := 0
                    long_cued := false

            if short_cued
                bool cue_condition = cue_state == 1 ? down_or_neutral : state_down

                if cue_condition
                    tp_price := close - take_profit_price
                    entry_price := close
                    stop_price := close + stop_loss_price

                    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, alert_message = sell_string)
                    strategy.exit("Short Exit", "Short", stop = stop_price, limit = tp_price, alert_profit = close_trade, alert_loss = close_trade)


                    cue_state := 0
                    short_cued := false

            if neutral_cued
                if state_up
                    tp_price := close + take_profit_price
                    entry_price := close
                    stop_price := close - stop_loss_price

                    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, alert_message = buy_string)
                    strategy.exit("Long Exit", "Long", stop = stop_price, limit = tp_price, alert_profit = close_trade, alert_loss = close_trade)

                    cue_state := 0
                    neutral_cued := false

                if state_down
                    tp_price := close - take_profit_price
                    entry_price := close
                    stop_price := close + stop_loss_price

                    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, alert_message = sell_string)
                    strategy.exit("Short Exit", "Short", stop = stop_price, limit = tp_price, alert_profit = close_trade, alert_loss = close_trade)

                    cue_state := 0
                    neutral_cued := false

        if enable_continuation and not stop_continuation
            if continuation_up and state_up and enable_long
                tp_price := close + take_profit_price
                entry_price := close
                stop_price := close - stop_loss_price

                strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, alert_message = buy_string)
                strategy.exit("Long Exit", "Long", stop = stop_price, limit = tp_price, alert_profit = close_trade, alert_loss = close_trade)

                cue_state := 0
                long_cued := false
                short_cued := false
                neutral_cued := false

            if continuation_down and state_down and enable_short
                tp_price := close - take_profit_price
                entry_price := close
                stop_price := close + stop_loss_price

                strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, alert_message = sell_string)
                strategy.exit("Short Exit", "Short", stop = stop_price, limit = tp_price, alert_profit = close_trade, alert_loss = close_trade)

                cue_state := 0
                long_cued := false
                short_cued := false
                neutral_cued := false

if in_trade and enable_break_even and not broke_even
    if in_long and high >= (entry_price + break_even_price)
        stop_price := entry_price + breaK_even_ticks
        strategy.exit("Long Exit", "Long", stop = stop_price, limit = tp_price, alert_profit = close_trade, alert_loss = close_trade)
        broke_even := true

    if in_short and low <= (entry_price - break_even_price)
        stop_price := entry_price - breaK_even_ticks
        strategy.exit("Short Exit", "Short", stop = stop_price, limit = tp_price, alert_profit = close_trade, alert_loss = close_trade)
        broke_even := true

// end strategy execution }```


I was trying to have a stop loss limit order but what I got was a stop loss level that acted like a market order on bar close. 

